# How to create BindingList which is subset of DbSet while using Table Per Hierachy inheritance approach?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have an `DbSet<Person>` which contains objects of type: `Person`, `Client`,`Employee` which are indicated by the discriminator in the table. I used table per hierarchy approach.

Now I try to get `BindingList` of `Client` only to set it as `DataSource` of the `ListBox`.

I was able to set whole  `People` table as the `DataSource` but I want only clients form this table in the `ListBox`.

```
 public partial class ListOfClientsForm : Form { 
    private ApplicationDbContext context;
    public BindingList<Person> Clients { get; set; }
        public BindingSource pSource { get; set; }
        public ListOfClientsForm() {
            InitializeComponent();
            context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            PopulateListBox();
        }

        public void PopulateListBox() {
            context.People.Load();
            Clients = context.People.Local.ToBindingList();
            Clients.AllowEdit = true;
            Clients.AllowNew = true;
            pSource = new BindingSource();
            pSource.DataSource = Clients;
            clientsListbox.DataSource = pSource; //now whole contents of the array is in the ListBox
        }
     }
```

To conclude I wish to have `public BindingList<Clients> Clients { get; set; }` instead of  `public BindingList<Person> Clients { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bring only the `Clients` elements into the context, then you can filter the people before load them:

```
context.People.OfType<Client>().Load();
//You are going to get only the clients
Clients = context.People.Local.ToBindingList();
```

Comment: Then if I add anything to that `BindingList` would it also be added to the `DbSet<Person> People` automatically? Do I have to save context afterwards?

Comment: Yes, it will be added to your context and you need to save changes afterwards in case you want to save the new element in the DB

Comment: Excuse me, one more question: Should I use `BindingSource` of any sort or do it directly as you showed me\?

Comment: If you want, but you can also set the `DataSource` of your `ListBox` with the `BindingList`. I recommend you read this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/09/08/data-binding-with-dbcontext.aspx), the  Winform Experience section. There you will find an example where it is used a `BindingSource`

Comment: Hello @Yoda, Did you try the solution that I suggested in my answer?

Comment: I am trying it now but, there is a problem with casting I cannot cast to `BindingList<Client>` from `BindingList<Person>` ||||  `context.People.OfType<Client>().Load();
            clientsListbox.DataSource = Clients = context.People.Local.ToBindingList() as BindingList<Client>;` because I got `BindingList<Client> Clients {get;set;}`

Comment: Oh it loads all of them: Person, Client and Employee.

Comment: That's weird, I just tested again and it works, this is what I'm doing: `context.People.OfType<Client>().Load(); this.listBox1.DataSource= Clients= context.People.Local.ToBindingList();`, but my `Clients` property is `BindingList<Person>`

Comment: It works but loads instances of `Person` and every subclass' of the `Person`?

Comment: No, it should load the elements of `Client` type only. That's what I'm getting when I use that code, the only problem here you are assigning the loaded elements in a `BindindList<Person>`, but that is not a problem, you can add, delete, even modify an element casting to `Client` in case you need to change the value of an specific property of that type